# Inexplicable error when running tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I get [this error](http://pastebin.com/fqbKxLfa) when I try to run `rake test:profile`. The error is coming from `test_homepage` which is in this file:

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'rails/performance_test_help'

# Profiling results for each test method are written to tmp/performance.
class BrowsingTest < ActionDispatch::PerformanceTest
  def test_homepage
    get '/'
  end
end
```

I don't understand why running this test has anything to do with creating a bank. Can anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: Can you post your db/seeds.rb file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using fixtures?  If so, double check to see that data in your fixtures aren't violating a uniqueness constraint on one (or more) of your database tables.

I've had this issue before when creating a table with a unique index:

```
create_table "companies" do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.text     "description"
end

add_index "companies", "name", :unique => true
```

By default, the fixture for this model would get generated with non-unique data for the `name` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume this is a fresh test suite and you haven't updated  your `fixtures/bank.yml` file with real data and you may actually have an ID field in it too, maybe?

Without seeing that fixture it's all guess work, but take a look at that.